# TeamCity: How do you report low unit test coverage?

Tags: unit-testing, continuous-integration, teamcity, code-coverage

We use TeamCity 7 (upgrade to 8 is possible) for continuous integration and we set ourselves a target of unit test coverage 90%. I know how to fail the build if the coverage is lower, but I'd not like to do so, as a missing test will slow down all the development.

On the other hand, I'd like to have clear visibility on the build overview page that the coverage is low - the only option I see is a service message like this one:

```
##teamcity[buildStatus status='SUCCESS' text='WARN: Test coverage only 89% {build.status.text}']
```

But that won't send any notification. Do you have any other suggestions, please?

Comment: BTW: Metrics like test-coverage are a great guide for developers, but setting targets such as yours often results in code designed to meet these arbitrary targets, rather then meeting customer quality needs. For example, if you have a DTO you'll end up writing code to test its getters and setters just to reach the 90% target you've set, but which add absolutely no value to the code and no value to your customer. Showing the coverage reports in TC is a good idea, but setting targets is generally considered a bad idea.

Comment: `[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]` attribute is available to rectify this

Answer (score 2):

Set the coverage html as artifact and link to it from Teamcity. IE setup a new tab, it will look something like this.

[image]